# Joining tables in SQL. Linking by column in the from clause

Tags: sql, join

Linking multiple tables, 
 Is there a chance I will output a different result if I call the column names to be linked in a different order in the `FROM` clause, by the `=` operator? 
 *For example:*

```
SELECT *    
FROM tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.colX = tbl2.colX
JOIN tbl3 on tbl2.colY = tbl3.colY
```

To be clear what I am asking, in the next block I switched positions for `tbl2.colX` and `tbl1.colX`

```
SELECT *    
FROM tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 on tbl2.colX = tbl1.colX
JOIN tbl3 on tbl2.colY = tbl3.colY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, order of columns in RDBMS "equals" operator is 100% equivalent.

I prefer the second form.. putting the *dependent* columns first in the "equals" join condition. For example, `join ORDER on ORDER.FK_CUSTOMER=CUSTOMER.ID` when I'm joining Order from Customer.

I also like to call my primary keys `ID` and my foreign keys `FK_<TableOrRole>`. Nice and clear.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't matter. But the order of the JOIN statements can affect the result. But if you are concerned about the order of the columns you should specify them in the order you require (after the SELECT and before the FROM) 
Also if you are not using all the data from all the joined tables then you don't need to select it all.

Comment: How would the order of (inner) joins affect the result?